# pandas join consecutive rows group by timedelta64[ns] column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'process': ['buying','selling','searhicng','repairing', 'preparing', 'selling','buying', 'searching', 'selling','searching'],
        'type': ['in_progress','in_progress','end','in_progress', 'end', 'in_progress','in_progress', 'end', 'in_progress','end'],
'country': ['usa',np.nan, 'usa','ghana', np.nan,'end','portugal', np.nan, np.nan,'england'],
'id': ['022','022','022', '011','011', '011','011', '011', '011','011'],
        'lag': ['00:00:10.042721','00:00:00.042721','00:00:05.042721','00:10:00.042721','00:00:00.042721','00:00:00.042721','00:00:50.042721','00:00:00.042721','00:00:00.042721','00:00:00.042721'],
        'created': ['2021-07-01','2021-07-02','2021-07-03','2021-07-04','2021-07-05','2021-07-06','2021-07-06','2021-07-08','2021-07-09','2021-07-10'],
        'next_created': ['2021-07-01','2021-07-02','2021-07-03','2021-07-04','2021-07-05','2021-07-06','2021-07-07','2021-07-08','2021-07-09','2021-07-10']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['process','type','country', 'id','lag','created','next_created'])
```

[image]

I need to concatenate consecutive rows by the `process` column for each group by `id`, which have `lag` less than `one second`, write the value of the first row to `created`, and `created_next` the value of the last line.

Can anyone see the problem, i don't understand how i can use groupby in this situation.

I guess that i need to use `cumsum()`, but i don't know what i can use in the `???` place

```
df['lag'].shift(1).???.cumsum()
```

Output result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# Convert to timedelta to facilitate checking of within one second
df['lag'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['lag'])

# Grouping by `lag` difference is less than one second within the same `id`
group = df['lag'].diff().abs().gt(np.timedelta64(1, 's')).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()

# Group by `id` and newly created grouping and then aggregate
(df.groupby(['id', group], as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg({'process': lambda x: ' '.join(x),   # concatenate consecutive rows within total grouping
         'type': 'first',
         'country': lambda x: x.iloc[0],     # get first entry including `NaN`
         'id': 'first',
         'lag': 'first',
         'created': 'first',                 # get first entry 
         'next_created': 'last'              # get last entry   
        })
)
```

**Result:**

```
                       process         type   country   id                    lag     created next_created
0                       buying  in_progress       usa  022 0 days 00:00:10.042721  2021-07-01   2021-07-01
1                      selling  in_progress       NaN  022 0 days 00:00:00.042721  2021-07-02   2021-07-02
2                    searhicng          end       usa  022 0 days 00:00:05.042721  2021-07-03   2021-07-03
3                    repairing  in_progress     ghana  011 0 days 00:10:00.042721  2021-07-04   2021-07-04
4            preparing selling          end       NaN  011 0 days 00:00:00.042721  2021-07-05   2021-07-06
5                       buying  in_progress  portugal  011 0 days 00:00:50.042721  2021-07-06   2021-07-07
6  searching selling searching          end       NaN  011 0 days 00:00:00.042721  2021-07-08   2021-07-10
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @formanite  Welcome!  Pleased to help!

Comment: Yes,  i've already voted)

Comment: @formanite  Thanks for that :-)